# Mongo query to access nested arrays in the schema

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Below is the mongodb schema I have

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5d637b5ce27c7d60e5c42ae7"),
  "name": "Bangalore",
  "movies": [
    {
      "name": "KGF",
      "theatres": [
        {
          "name": "PVR",
          "seats": 45
        },
        {
          "name": "IMAX",
          "seats": 46
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Avengers",
      "theatres": [
        {
          "name": "IMAX",
          "seats": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "_class": "com.BMS_mongo.ZZ_BMS_mongo_demo.Entity.CityInfo"
}
```

I want to access the value of seats available in Bangalore city for the movie "Avengers". The query should return me the integer value of the seats available.

I have written this code

```
MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);  
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("BMSdb");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("cities");

AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(
                                            Arrays.asList(                                           
           Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("name" , cityname)),                                                  
           Aggregates.unwind("$movies"),                                                     
           Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("movies.name" , moviename)),                                                  
           Aggregates.unwind("$movies.theatres"),                                                    
           Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("movies.theatres.name" , cinemaname)),                                                    
           Aggregates.group("$movies.theatres.seats")
            )
        );

List<Object> res = new ArrayList<>();

for(Document d : output) {
    res.add(d.get("_id"));
}

Integer currentSeats = Integer.parseInt(res.get(0).toString());
```

"output" has the following document -

```
Document{{_id=50}}
```

I am able to retrieve the number of seats but is there any other way of getting the seats available using mongo query only...

Also I need to update the seats as well .... how can I do that ?